# Is it true that Korean nouns and pronouns use different particles?

Tags: grammar, particle

I've heard that there's some particle in Korean that can only be attached to nouns but never pronouns - and pronouns use some different particle instead.

Is it true?

Comment: Did your source give any examples?

Comment: It did, but I've read about it like 6 years ago or so - so I don't remember, unfortunately (tried googling it - found nothing). It mentioned something about one particle that only pronouns can attach in Korean, but never nouns - that's pretty much all I remember.

P.S. It's possible that that source was wrong though - that's what I'm trying to find out.

Comment: 나는 학교에 간다 I go to a school vs 나는 그녀에게 간다 I go to her. We can not switch 에, 에게.

Comment: @HK Lee Also grammatical are "나는 거기에 간다" and "나는 친구에게 간다", but not "나는 거기에게 간다"  or "나는 친구에 간다." Your example is related to the different semantics of 학교 and 그녀 (maybe human/non-human or animate/inanimate), not their being noun or pronoun.

Comment: Can't really think of an example myself, but would be very interested if somebody comes up with one.

Comment: There is `들` which can't go with only *some* pronouns. E.g. `꽃들`, `멍멍이들`, `자동차들`, `우리들`, `저희들`, `너희들`, `네놈들`, `그들`, `이자들`, `그자들`, `저자들`, `그대들`, `당신들` but `나+들`, `너+들`

Comment: There is `ㅣ가` which works only with pronouns `나` and `너`. `내가`. `네가`. But we cannot say `나+가` or `너+가`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say it is *false*.

There are hundreds of Korean pronouns in the Standard Korean Language Dictionary (SKLD) and 47 pronouns have often been used in speaking or writing according to [한국어 학습용 어휘 목록](https://www.korean.go.kr/front/etcData/etcDataView.do?mn_id=46&etc_seq=71). The 47 can be put into two categories:

- Person/people: 나, 저 (as in 저 대신), 자기, 너, 당신, 자네, 너희, 여러분, 우리, 저희, 이 (as in 이들), 그, 그녀, 저 (as in 저들), 이쪽, 그쪽, 저쪽, 이것 (= 이거), 그것 (= 그거), 저것 (= 저거), 누구, 이곳, 거기, 아무, 모 (as in 김 모 씨), 이분, 그이, 그분, 그대, 이놈, 그놈, 아무개, 저편
- Thing(s): 이, 그, 저 (as in 이도 저도), 이것 (= 이거), 저것 (= 저거), 그것 (= 그거, 거), 뭐, 무엇 (= 뭣, 무어), 어디, 여기, 거기, 저기, 이곳, 그곳, 저곳, 언제, 이쪽, 그쪽, 저쪽, 저편

By contrast, 3404 nouns are listed there. The 50 most frequently used nouns can be grouped as follows:

- Person/people: 사람, 인간, 남자, 여자, 여성, 아버지, 어머니, 아이 (= 애), 친구, 대통령, 자신
- Thing(s): 때 (as in 아무 때), 말 (as in 할 말), 일 (as in 할 일), 사회, 집, 문제, 안 (as in 건물 안), 속, 경우, 문화, 생각, 소리, 정도, 앞, 뒤, 후(後), 시간, 사실, 눈 (as in 초롱초롱한 눈), 점(點), 시대, 다음, 전(前), 곳, 세계, 위 (as in 산 위), 운동, 학교, 정부, 돈, 국가, 날, 마음, 관계, 몸, 얼굴, 지역, 모습, 물 (as in 마실 물)

The number of 조사(助詞) is smaller than 200 according to the SKLD. Some of them can be categorized as follows:

- 주격 조사: 이/가, 께서, 서 (as in 혼자서), 에서
- 보격 조사: 이/가
- 서술격 조사: 이다
- 관형격 조사: 의
- 목적격 조사: 을/를/ㄹ
- 부사격 조사: 에, 에서 (= 서), 에게, 께, 으로/로, 와/과, 같이, 처럼, 보다, 으로서/로서, 으로부터/로부터, 한테, 에다가 (= 에다), 만큼, 만치, 하고, 에게서, 한테서, 에서부터 (= 서부터), 로써, 랑/이랑, 보고, 마따나
- 호격 조사: 아/야, 여/이여, 이시여
- 인용격 조사: 고, 라고/이라고, 하고
- 보조사: 은/는/ㄴ, 도, 만, 까지, 부터, 나/이나, 밖에, 마다, 뿐, 야/이야, 란/이란, 대로, 조차, 마저, 요, 야말로/이야말로, 다가 (= 다), 나마/이나마, 은커녕/는커녕/커녕, 치고, 거나, 라도/이라도, 든지 (= 든), 든가, 따라, 마는, 그려, 깨나, ㄹ랑/일랑
- 접속 조사: 와/과, 나/이나, 다, 하고, 랑/이랑, 라든가/이라든가, 라든지/이라든지, 며/이며, 이고, 니/이니, 하며

Here, I am bringing usage examples to check whether each 조사 can be directly attached to at least one pronoun (≪P≫) or at least one noun (≪N≫), or neither of them. I will ignore irrelevant examples including numerals or other words.

- 주격 조사

  - 이/가: ≪P≫ **내**가 와서 **이것**이 나왔다. / ≪N≫ **아이**가 와서 **말**이 나왔다.
  - 께서: ≪P≫ **그분**께서 / ≪N≫ **아버지**께서
  - 서: ≪N≫ *(used only as)* **혼자**서
  - 에서: ≪P≫ **저쪽**에서 / ≪N≫ **학교**에서
- 보격 조사

  - 이/가: ≪P≫ **내**가 아니라 **그놈**이 있다. / ≪N≫ **친구**가 아니라 **돈**이 있다.
- 서술격 조사

  - 이다: ≪P≫ **나**이다 (= **나**다), **이것**이다 / ≪N≫ **아이**이다 (= **아이**다), **말**이다
- 관형격 조사

  - 의: ≪P≫ **나**의 / ≪N≫ **아이**의
- 목적격 조사

  - 을/를/ㄹ: ≪P≫ **나**를, **날**, **이것**을 / ≪N≫ **아이**를, **아일**, **말**을
- 부사격 조사

  - 에: ≪P≫ **이것**에 / ≪N≫ **말**에
  - 에서 (= 서): ≪P≫ **저쪽**에서 / ≪N≫ **학교**에서
  - 에게: ≪P≫ **나**에게 / ≪N≫ **아이**에게
  - 께: ≪P≫ **그분**께 / ≪N≫ **아버지**께
  - 으로/로: ≪P≫ **저쪽**으로, **거기**로 / ≪N≫ **지역**으로, **학교**로
  - 와/과: ≪P≫ **나**와 함께, **이것**과 같이 / ≪N≫ **아이**와 함께, **말**과 같이
  - 같이: ≪P≫ **나**같이 / ≪N≫ **아이**같이
  - 처럼: ≪P≫ **나**처럼 / ≪N≫ **아이**처럼
  - 보다: ≪P≫ **나**보다 / ≪N≫ **아이**보다
  - 으로서/로서: ≪P≫ **이쪽**으로서, **나**로서 / ≪N≫ **대통령**으로서, **아이**로서
  - 으로부터/로부터: ≪P≫ **이쪽**으로부터, **저들**로부터 / ≪N≫ **집**으로부터, **친구**로부터
  - 한테: ≪P≫ **나**한테 / ≪N≫ **아이**한테
  - 에다가 (= 에다): ≪P≫ 상자는 **이곳**에다가 두어라. / ≪N≫ 상자는 **집**에다가 두어라.
  - 만큼: ≪P≫ 그곳은 **이곳**만큼 크다. / ≪N≫ 우리 집은 친구 **집**만큼 크다.
  - 만치: ≪P≫ 그곳은 **이곳**만치 크다. / ≪N≫ 우리 집은 친구 **집**만치 크다.
  - 하고: ≪P≫ 너는 **나**하고 닮았다. / ≪N≫ 아이는 **어머니**하고 닮았다.
  - 에게서: ≪P≫ **당신**에게서 온 편지 / ≪N≫ **어머니**에게서 온 편지
  - 한테서: ≪P≫ **너**한테서 온 편지 / ≪N≫ **아이**한테서 온 편지
  - 에서부터 (= 서부터): ≪P≫ **여기**에서부터 삼십 분을 가라. / ≪N≫ **집**에서부터 삼십 분을 가라.
  - 로써/으로써: ≪P≫ **그**로써 **이것**으로써 문제를 해결하라. / ≪N≫ **소리**로써 **몸**으로써 문제를 해결하라.
  - 랑/이랑: ≪P≫ **나**랑 같이 가서 **그놈**이랑 싸우자. / ≪N≫ **친구**랑 같이 가서 **시간**이랑 싸우자.
  - 보고: ≪P≫ **누구**보고 하는 소리인가? / ≪N≫ **친구**보고 할 소리인가?
  - 마따나: ≪N≫ *(used only as)* **말**마따나, **말씀**마따나
- 호격 조사

  - 아/야: ≪P≫ **이놈**아! **아무개**야!  / ≪N≫ **인간**아! **친구**야!
  - 여/이여: ≪P≫ **아무개**여! **그대들**이여! / ≪N≫ **친구**여! **인간**이여!
  - 이시여: ≪P≫ **여러분**이시여! / ≪N≫ **대통령**이시여!
- 인용격 조사

  - 고: *(not attached to nouns/pronouns)*
  - 라고/이라고: ≪P≫ **그대**라고, **여러분**이라고 / ≪N≫ **친구**라고, **사람**이라고
- 보조사

  - 은/는/ㄴ: ≪P≫ **이것**은, **나**는, **난** / ≪N≫ **말**은, **아이**는, **아인**
  - 도: ≪P≫ **이분**도 / ≪N≫ **친구**도
  - 만: ≪P≫ **이분**만 / ≪N≫ **친구**만
  - 까지: ≪P≫ **거기**까지 / ≪N≫ **속**까지
  - 부터: ≪P≫ **이곳**부터 / ≪N≫ **위**부터
  - 나/이나: ≪P≫ **나**나 **너**나 **이것**이나 가지자. / ≪N≫ **앞**이나 **뒤**나 엉망이다.
  - 밖에: ≪P≫ **이분**밖에 / ≪N≫ **친구**밖에
  - 마다: ≪P≫ **무엇**마다 / ≪N≫ **지역**마다
  - 뿐: ≪P≫ **이분**뿐 / ≪N≫ **친구**뿐
  - 야/이야: ≪P≫ **이거**야 문제없고 **이분**이야 괜찮지. / ≪N≫ **소리**야 문제없고 **생각**이야 괜찮지.
  - 란/이란: ≪P≫ **아무개**란 무엇이고 **무엇**이란 무엇인가? / ≪N≫ **친구**란 무엇이고 **사람**이란 무엇인가?
  - 대로: ≪P≫ **그것**대로 / ≪N≫ **사실**대로
  - 조차: ≪P≫ **그것**조차 / ≪N≫ **사실**조차
  - 마저: ≪P≫ **그것**마저 / ≪N≫ **사실**마저
  - 요: ≪P≫ **우리**요 어디로 가요? / ≪N≫ **일**요 어떻게 할까요?
  - 야말로/이야말로: ≪P≫ **우리**야말로, **이쪽**이야말로 / ≪N≫ **문제**야말로, **일**이야말로
  - 다가 (= 다): ≪P≫ *(used only as)* **거기**다가, **여기**다가, **저기**다가
  - 나마/이나마: ≪P≫ **우리**나마, **그곳**이나마 / ≪N≫ **아이**나마, **몸**이나마
  - 은커녕/는커녕/커녕: ≪P≫ **우리**는커녕, **그곳**은커녕, **그**커녕 / ≪N≫ **아이**는커녕, **몸**은커녕, **일**커녕
  - 치고: ≪P≫ **그놈**치고 / ≪N≫ **시대**치고
  - 거나: ≪P≫ **언제**거나 / ≪N≫ **문화**거나
  - 라도/이라도: ≪P≫ **이거**라도, **이것**이라도 / ≪N≫ **국가**라도, **마음**이라도
  - 든지 (= 든): ≪P≫ **이거**든지 / ≪N≫ **국가**든지
  - 든가: ≪P≫ **이거**든가 / ≪N≫ **국가**든가
  - 따라: ≪N≫ *(used only for a limited set of nouns)* **그날**따라, **오늘**따라
  - 마는: *(not attached to nouns/pronouns)*
  - 그려: *(not attached to nouns/pronouns)*
  - 깨나: ≪N≫ *(used only for what you can possess much)* **돈**깨나, **심술**깨나
  - ㄹ랑/일랑: ≪P≫ **거길**랑, **그곳**일랑 / ≪N≫ **문젤**랑, **학교**일랑
- 접속 조사

  - 와/과: ≪P≫ **나**와 너, **이곳**과 저곳 / ≪N≫ **사회**와 국가, **전**과 후
  - 나/이나: ≪P≫ **나**나 너, **이곳**이나 저곳 / ≪N≫ **사회**나 국가, **전**이나 후
  - 다: ≪P≫ **이거**다 **저거**다 하지 마라. / ≪N≫ **아버지**다 **어머니**다 성심껏 모셔라.
  - 하고: ≪P≫ **나**하고 **너**하고 함께 가자. / ≪N≫ **몸**하고 **마음**하고 따로 논다.
  - 랑/이랑: ≪P≫ **이거**랑 **저거**랑 다 먹고 **이놈**이랑 **저놈**이랑 다 데려와. / ≪N≫ **남자**랑 **여자**랑 다 데려와서 **생각**이랑 **말**이랑 다 하자.
  - 라든가/이라든가: ≪P≫ **언제**라든가 **무엇**이라든가 결정할 사항 / ≪N≫ **학교**라든가 **집**이라든가 하는 장소
  - 라든지/이라든지: ≪P≫ **언제**라든지 **무엇**이라든지 결정할 사항 / ≪N≫ **학교**라든지 **집**이라든지 하는 장소
  - 며/이며: ≪P≫ **언제**며 **무엇**이며 결정할 사항 / ≪N≫ **학교**며 **집**이며 하는 장소
  - 고/이고: ≪P≫ **언제**고 **무엇**이고 다 결정해야 한다. / ≪N≫ **학교**고 **집**이고 사람이 있는 곳이다.
  - 니/이니: ≪P≫ **이거**니 **저것**이니 다 먹자. / ≪N≫ **학교**니 **집**이니 어디든 가자.
  - 하며: ≪P≫ **이곳**하며 **저곳**하며 망가진 것 / ≪N≫ **돈**하며 **시간**하며 한정된 일

In general, nouns and pronouns can have the same particles. We can conclude that *some* particles are attached to specific nominal words/phrases or none of them. It is *not quite correct* to state that nouns and pronouns have different particles; I mean, **particles determine what can come before them**.

Answer (score 0):

Not really, I think. But I can find similar thing.

As Taegyung said, Can use '에게, 께, 한테' to animacy noun, and '에' to inanimacy noun.

For example, you can say '그에게 가다'(go to him), not '그에 가다'.

Here is example sentence that Korean often say wrong : '*일본에게 답하다'(answer to japan)

this one is wrong because '일본'(Japan) is inanimacy noun. '일본에 답하다' is correct.